# String index out of range for recursion method

Tags: java

Writing a recursion method with a helper but I keep getting string index out of bounds when initializing my recursion counter equal to string length.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    printSlowly("This program will take a string from you and find the number of occurrences of a given letter in the string,"
            + "\nPlease enter your string and press enter: ",50);
    String userString = in.nextLine();
    printSlowly("Now please enter a character: ",50);
    String userChar = in.nextLine();
    getNumChar(userString,userChar);
}
```

//recursion method

```
public static void getNumChar(String userString, String userChar) {
    
        int count = 0;
        int i = userString.length();
        getNumChar(userString, userChar, count, i);

}
```

//Helper

```
public static void getNumChar(String userString, String userChar, int count, int i) {
    
    char s = userString.charAt(i);
    String s2= String.valueOf(s);  
    
    if (i<0) {
        
    }
    else if (s2 == userChar) {
        count++;
        i--;
        getNumChar(userString, userChar, count, i);
    }
    else {
        i--;
        getNumChar(userString, userChar, count, i);
        
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
```

Comment: What are you supplying as input?  What line does the error message refer to?

Comment: Side note: usually one is expected to learn about returning values from functions *before* diving into recursion... I'd strongly recommend to have simpler version of your code that for example just count if first character matches and get it working first.

Comment: Use equals to compare strings not ==

Answer (score 0):

You don't wanna change your index variable i, that's what the count is for. When your count reaches i then you should stop